# How can I get the Tripp-Lite KVM Switch work on Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, keyboard, mouse, kvm-switch

I have a Tripp-Lite KVM Switch model B020-008 and I'm trying to get it to work on Ubuntu version 10.04 LTS and 12.04 LTS but for some reason it only barely works on 10.04 LTS meaning the mouse barely moves and keyboard does not work at all.

Is there a package in the repositories that could make this device work? I tried going on Tripp-Lite's website but found no drivers nor firmware for it. Heck not even for Windows there is nothing on this; only a manual. I'm guessing it should be plug and play but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your server or computer with the port it's on selected and the kvm plugged, no  drivers needed.

Comment: I've found that this works best if the system is on the active port completely through the boot process. If that fails, consider swapping some cables to see if the problem follows the cable or the port

Comment: Wait so what your saying is that I have to restart all of my servers while they are on the port and then they will all work, yeah that makes no sense. They should just work. Cables are straight from TripLite.